# Get envato private collection

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to get my own private collection on Envato themeforest market using their new API.. I keep getting "Not found: no such endpoint" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$url = "https://api.envato.com/v3/market/user/collection=8104310";
$curl = curl_init($url);

$personal_token = "";
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$personal_token;
$header[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0';
$header[] = 'timeout: 20';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);

$envatoRes = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$envatoRes = json_decode($envatoRes);
```

I couldn't find the proper url anywhere.

Comment: When I hit the URL, I get a missing token and not `"Not found: no such endpoint"`.

Comment: yes that is just to show the curl url I am using in php

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code before.

Comment: Your `$personal_token = "";` is empty. It will need a token for authentication.

Comment: Yes I removed that so not to post it here. it's in the actual code. Anyway now it is working for some reason. I replaced the $url with this value 'https://api.envato.com/v3/market/user/collection?id=8104310'  ... which I thought I had already tried a million times. But it's working now.

Comment: ok, so `id` was the missing query parameter in your case.

Comment: Exactly. I thought I had already tried it with id parameter. Then got the url from the inspector network tab and it worked. I must have missed something before.

Answer (score 0):

The request had to be:

```
$url = "https://api.envato.com/v3/market/user/collection?id=8104310";
```

Which I thought I had already tried.